# curl from one docker container to another gives 302 on Jenkins server, but works locally

Tags: linux, docker, jenkins, networking, docker-compose

I've got a docker-compose file with 3 services:

1. database
2. api
3. [locust](https://locust.io/) container to load test the api

This is my (simplified) docker-compose file.

```
version: "2.0"
services:
  database:
    image: ourcompany/postgres11
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: thedatabase
      POSTGRES_USER: theuser
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: thepassword
  api:
    build: ./api
    volumes:
      - ./api/src:/app
    ports:
      - "8001:8001"
    links:
      - database
    environment:
      - DATABASE_HOST=database
      - DATABASE_NAME=thedatabase
      - DATABASE_USER=theuser
      - DATABASE_PASSWORD=thepassword
      - UWSGI_HTTP=0.0.0.0:8001
    # and some more env variables
  locust:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - ./reports:/opt/reports
      - ./:/opt/src
    links:
      - api
    command: bash -c "locust -L DEBUG -f /opt/src/locustfile.py --host=http://api:8001 --no-web -c 25 -r 5 --run-time 15s"
```

When I run this locally on my laptop (Ubuntu 19.04) it works great. But when running this on our Jenkins CI server (Ubuntu 16.04), the locust container isn't able to call the api.

So I created this `curl` command to manually try the post:

```
curl -v -d '{"id":"260b748f-dad4-42ba-84b4-9084ea5d8304","count":"6.0","sensor":"AAG-1-4"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://api:8001/v0/measurement/
```

I execced into the locust container on my laptop (`docker exec -it ee470aaea287 bash`) and tried the curl post from there, which worked perfectly (I had verbose mode enabled):

```
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
*   Trying 192.168.208.3...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to api (192.168.208.3) port 8001 (#0)
> POST /v0/measurement/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: api:8001
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 407
> 
* upload completely sent off: 407 out of 407 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 201 Created
< Content-Type: application/json
< Vary: Accept
< Allow: POST, LIST, GET
< X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM *
< Content-Length: 511
< 
* Connection #0 to host api left intact
{"success": "true"}
```

I then ssh'ed into the jenkins server and ran the curl request from outside the container with `api` replaced by `127.0.0.1`. That worked perfectly again (similar output as above).

I then execced into the locust container on the Jenkins server and tried the curl post from there:

```
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
*   Trying 10.240.2.1...
* Connected to 10.240.2.1 (10.240.2.1) port 8080 (#0)
> POST http://api:8001/v0/measurement/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: api:8001
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
> Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 407
> 
* upload completely sent off: 407 out of 407 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
< Date: Wed, 14 Aug 2019 07:18:28 GMT
* HTTP/1.1 proxy connection set close!
< Proxy-Connection: close
< Via: 1.1 localhost.localdomain
< Proxy-agent: 
< Location: http://www.api.com:8001/v0/measurement/
< Content-Length: 487
< Content-Type: text/html
< 
<HEAD><TITLE>Moved Temporarily</TITLE></HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="white" FGCOLOR="black"><H1>Moved Temporarily</H1><HR>
<FONT FACE="Helvetica,Arial"><B>
Description: <TEXTAREA READONLY rows="2" cols="75"> The document you requested is now <a href="http://www.api.com:8001/v0/measurement/">http://www.api.com:8001/v0/measurement/</a>.  Please update your documents and bookmarks accordingly.</TEXTAREA></B></FONT>
<HR>
<!-- default "Moved Temporarily" response (302) -->
</BODY>
* Closing connection 0
```

As you can see that fails with a 302 redirect. There are a couple weird things in there:

1. it first talks about port 8080 even though I need to connect to port 8001. I don't expose those ports manually since that could conflict with other containers on the Jenkins server. As far as I understand docker takes care of this under the hood though.
2. it redirects to `www.api.com`. What part of the system does this?

I then tried pinging the api container from within the locust container, which works perfectly:

```
$ ping api
PING api (192.168.32.3) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from api_1.default (192.168.32.3): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.127 ms
64 bytes from api_1.default (192.168.32.3): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.056 ms
64 bytes from api_1.default (192.168.32.3): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.065 ms
```

and telnet:

```
telnet api 8001
Trying 192.168.32.3...
Connected to api.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

Does anybody know how I can debug this further?

Comment: Try exposing port 8001 in the docker-compose file. map it in port section 8001: 8001

Comment: @TreantBG - I tried that, but it gives the same result. I also added info on pinging and telnetting from locust to the api container (which worked).

Comment: Are the Docker versions the same?

Comment: @Hannes - Just checked. Both my laptop and the Jenkins server are on `Docker version 19.03.1, build 74b1e89e8a`

Comment: Is it possible that you are trying to access http:// www.api.com:8001/  on your jenkins server? From your laptop you are trying to access http:// api.com:8001/. Try it without the www...

Comment: @Hannes - From both my laptop and the Jenkins server I'm trying to connect to `api:8001`. I even copy pasted the exact curl command from my laptop to the server to avoid any typos. The exact same curl command works on my laptop, but not on the Jenkins server. My main question is: what returns the redirect? Which part of the system does that?

Comment: Are you using exactly the same images and share it via a registry or are you building it on the jenkins and laptop each?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197920/discussion-between-hannes-and-kramer65).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We figured out together with the thread creator that he runs a proxy in the network. Thats why it was not working.

A change in the docker environment variables does the trick:

```
  - http_proxy=
  - https_proxy=
  - no_proxy=
```

So the proxy is disabled inside the docker-container.

Comment: Fwiw, ref. the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/network/proxy/) “In Docker 17.07 and higher, you can [configure the Docker client](https://docs.docker.com/network/proxy/#configure-the-docker-client) to pass proxy information to containers automatically”.